# Git & Rails -- I messed up, can i revert to last commit (delete model/controller/migrations/code)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control

This is my first time using any sort of version control (git) and excited to get a chance to see how well this works... I'm a bit confused on what all it can though.

I have a master branch were I keep all my tested, everything works commits....and I'm currently on the development branch where I'm adding some new features.

I added a model/controller and migrated the database and created some routes.

I didnt commit any of these changes since I f*cked up in a major way somewhere in the process.

How can I revert back to the last state of the development branch...pre-generation of model/controller/migrations...where everything worked.

is there one command that will change the database as well as everything else..

I'm using rails 3 and sqlite, if that helps

thanks

Comment: Well you really shouldn't be storing your DB in version control.... But the reset HEAD^  will revert all the files. But if you've already migrated, you can either blow away your Devel DB and just re run your migrations or make sure to migrate down before you use git reset.  (else you can always just login to the DB and drop the tables it created, but not sure on how complicated the migrations you created where).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Revert to the latest HEAD with:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: I think that would reset to the second-to-latest HEAD (the `^`).

Comment: can't believe how often `git reset --hard HEAD^` is the answer :-)